# Why does cut -d ' ' not work with space in this case?

Tags: grep, cut

I've no issue with this `cut` command.

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo ab cd ef
ab cd ef

wolf@linux:~$ echo ab cd ef | cut -d ' ' -f 1
ab

wolf@linux:~$ echo ab cd ef | cut -d ' ' -f 2
cd
```

However, when I try the same command with different input like this, I did not get the output as expected.

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet '
    inet 10.10.10.10/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic eth0

wolf@linux:~$ ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1

wolf@linux:~$ ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

What's wrong in the second example?

`awk` doesn't seems to have a problem with the same input, strange.

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip address show eth0 | awk '/inet / {print $1}'
inet

wolf@linux:~$ ip address show eth0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
10.10.10.10/24
```

Comment: ... there are 4 spaces before `inet` ...?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. But why does awk doesn't have this issue? It works with the first argument.

Comment: @Wolf `awk` counts the first non-blank character as part of the first field, by default.

Comment: About the fact that it's manipulating IP addresses: `ip`'s JSON output  is meant to be parsed. Along with the `jq` command you can do this in shell. Eg: `ip -4 -json address show vboxnet0 | jq -j '.[] | .addr_info[] | .local, "/", .prefixlen, "\n"'`

Comment: Alternatively, `ip -4 -br a s eth0 | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: @A.B It seems that points are awarded for terseness, so `ip -4 -j a ls vboxnet0 | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info[] | "\(.local)/\(.prefixlen)"'`

Comment: @user1686 my jq foo is low, but i'm still learning (because of ip's JSON output).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cut` takes each and every delimiter as meaningful, even if there are consecutive spaces. This is unlike `awk`, which by default splits on whitespace, but takes multiple whitespace as only one delimiter, and ignore leading whitespace.

You could get awk to behave similarly by setting the field separator `FS` to `[ ]`:

```
$ ip add show lo | awk -F'[ ]' '$5 == "inet" {print $6}'
127.0.0.1/8
```

That has to be set like that, as a regexp, since a single space by itself in `FS` marks the default, special operation.

See, e.g. the GNU awk manual has to say [on field separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html).

Answer (score 6):

The line you grep from the output starts with 4 spaces, if you select the fifth field you'll get the first string:

```
admin:~ # ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d " " -f 5
inet
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But why does `awk` doesn't have this issue? It works with the first argument.

Comment: This is not an issue, it is different behaviour by design. `cut` uses a single character as a delimiter – *exactly* one space in your example. For the `$x` accessors, `awk` performs a shell-like expansion on the input, giving you access to the "words" separated by *at least* one white-space character.

Comment: By far the most straightforward way to work around this issue is to pass the input through `tr -s ' '` before `cut`. Counting spaces by hand is annoying, and may be fragile if the utility changes its output. Also, you can use the same `tr` invocation to collapse tabs and spaces if that turns out to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00001.html) that adds new `-m` command-line option to `cut`, which works in the field mode and treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.  This basically solves the OP's question in a rather efficient way.  I also submitted this patch upstream a couple of days ago, and let's hope that it will be merged into the coreutils project.

There are some [further thoughts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2023-08/msg00011.html) about adding even more whitespace-related features to `cut`, and having some feedback about all that would be great.  I'm willing to implement more patches for `cut` and submit them upstream, which would make this utility more versatile and more usable in various real-world scenarios.