# How to count spaces in text?

Tags: whitespace

In the following example, there are 4 spaces before inet.

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet '
    inet 10.10.10.10/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic eth0
wolf@linux:~$
```

How do I count the number of spaces like this example.

This sample is easy as it only has 4 spaces.

What if it has more than that? Hundreds, thousands?

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: "spaces" where? At the beginning of the line, [as you noticed previously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606639/why-does-cut-d-not-work-with-space-in-this-case), or in a particular line, or in all of the output? Because there are more than 4 spaces in the line of output that you showed.

Comment: Are you also considering tab characters as spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tr` to delete everything that’s not the character you’re interested in, the `wc` to count the remaining characters:

```
ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | tr -d -c ' ' | wc -m
```

This scales well to large amounts of text, `tr` is very efficient.

Note however that with some implementations of `tr` including GNU `tr`, that only works properly for single-byte characters (such as the space character).

If you only want to count leading spaces, you’ll need something a little more powerful than `tr`:

```
ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | sed 's/[^ ].*$//' | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
```

This deletes every part of each line which is not leading space, then deletes newlines and counts.

See [How to count the number of a specific character in each line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18736/86440) if you’re interested in counts per line.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, it works. I notice that `tr` also can be used to visualized the empty space, something like `tr ' ' '#'`. Is this the best way to visualize white space?

Comment: That’s a good way, whether it’s the best depends on circumstances (in particular, on whether `#` is already present).

Comment: Thanks for that link. Interesting topic

Comment: Would `grep -c ...` not work, with a suitable space pattern? The tr/wc is nice though

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `grep -c` counts matching lines, so you’d have to transform the input first.

Answer (score 7):

To count the number of space characters at the start of each line, you  could do:

```
awk -F '[^ ].*' '{print length($1)}'
```

Which prints the length (in number of characters) of the first field, where field are separated by any sequence of characters starting with a non-space.

To report the maximum amount of whitespace found at the start of any line of the input (the maximum indentation), with GNU `wc`:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]].*//' | wc -L
```

That reports that amount of whitespace in terms of *display width* on a display device where tab stops are 8 columns appart:

```
$ printf '\tfoo\n' | sed 's/[^[:blank:]].*//' | wc -L
8
```

```
$ printf '\u3000foo\n' | sed 's/[^[:blank:]].*//' | wc -L
2
```

The U+3000 character (the ideographic space character, classified as blank in my locale) is a double-width character encoded on 3 bytes in UTF-8.

If you'd rather wanted that maximum length to be reported in terms of number of characters:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]].*//;s/./x/g' | wc -L
```

(`s/./x/g` converts every character on each line to `x` which we know has a display width of 1).

Or in terms of number of bytes:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]].*//' |
  LC_ALL=C tr -c '\n' '[x*]' | # convert each byte other than newline to x
  wc -L
```

Comment: It's cool to find out so many things can be accomplished with `awk`. Thanks @Stéphane Chazelas

Answer (score 3):

- Print the number of leading spaces:

  ```
  awk '{print match($0,/[^ ]|$/)-1}' file
  ```

  `match($0,/[^ ]|$/)` matches the first non-space (`[^ ]`) or the end-of-line (`$`)
  and returns its position.
- Print the number of spaces:

  ```
  awk -F '[ ]' '{print (NF?NF-1:0)}' file
  ```

  `-F '[ ]'` sets the field separator to space. `NF` is the number of fields.
  The ternary expression means: "If NF is not 0, print NF-1, else print 0".
  This is because NF is 0 if the line is empty.

Comment: Or `print NF-!!NF`. See also `print gsub(" "," ")'`

Answer (score 2):

it reads like what you really want **is how to delete leading white space**

many ways to do that, assuming you want to do it in bash I found this from

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-leading-spaces-from-front-of-each-word.html

```
echo "     This is a test"

# remove leading white space on the output

echo "     This is a test" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

so in your case you could do

```
ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

also check out [How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102008/how-do-i-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-each-line-of-some-output)

Comment: Thanks @ron. I appreciate the answer and tips given.

Comment: In standard `sed` implementations, `[ \t]` matches on either SPC, backslash or `t`. GNU `sed` however only does it when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment. `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'` would be standard. It would remove spaces and tabs and all other characters classified as *blank* in the locale.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken below example

```
`echo "      praveen"| grep -o "^ *"| awk '{print length($0)}'`6

output

6
```

Python

```
>>> a="      praveen"
>>> import re
>>> k=re.compile(r'^ *')
>>> m=re.search(k,a)
>>> print len(m.group())
6
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ip address show eth0 \
| grep -oP '^\h*(?=inet\h)' \
| wc -m;
```

This uses GNU grep with PCRE mode and looks for any leading horizontal whitespace, aka, [[:blank :]], followed by inet and another blank. Then we feed it to wc to get a char count.

Using gnu awk with the FPATH variable set to a run of blanks.

```
$ ... |
 gawk -v FPAT='\\s*' '$0=length($1)""'
```

Using python list compression we can also feed grep's o/p to get the count.

```
$ ... | python3 -c 'import sys;print(*[len(l)-len(l.lstrip()) for l in sys.stdin],sep="\n")'
```

We can also feed the grep output to perl.

```
$ ..... |
  perl -F'\H' -pE '$_=$F[0]=~y///c'
```

Here we split the record on nonhorizontal whitespace and then replace every character in the first field, in a scalar context returns the translations done. Assign it to the record and have the -p option get it autoprinted.